# How I can create environment parameter in bash or from script

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I want to create env parameter 
    that the key is `a:b or a@b`
I need to do it from bash script or from terminal , it should work from linux or windows

when I tried it `export a:b=c`
I got an error

```
not a valid identifier
```

When I tried
`export tempKey = a:b` then It worked but then I didn't know how to use the value `a:b` to create it as key

Could you please advise ?

Comment: In standard shells, variable names consist of alphanumerics plus underscore, not starting with a digit.  The names cannot contain a colon or at-sign.  Some shells allow some extensions to this default character set.  If yours doesn't, there's nothing for it but to change shell, either by adapting the one you're using (get the source code, change it, recompile it) or by getting a shell that already supports the extended notation.  If you need portable shell scripts, don't use the extended notation.

Comment: Is it possible to write in shell script ?

Comment: Is it possible to write what in a shell script?  You got 'not a valid identifier' as an error, so your shell won't allow you to use `a:b` as a variable name.  Why do you think you need this facility?  The default solution is to use underscore in place of punctuation: `export a_b=c` is perfectly kosher in most Bourne-shell deriviatives (though not in the original Bourne shell).

Comment: to write not from git bash but from shell script export a:b=c

Comment: I need it for npm env to change the environment value so the  key should be npm_config_key=value the probelm that my key is with annotation scope meaning @myScope:key=value so how I can do it and add environment variable in this case?

Comment: so in my case that value that I need to add is npm_config_@myscope:npmKey=npmValue

Comment: It sounds like you need an [associative array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) in Bash.  `declare -A npm_config; npm_config["myscope:npmKey"]=npmValue; echo ${npm_config["myscope:npmKey"]}`.  However, be a bit cautious: if you need to include the array reference inside a double quoted string in the argument to `echo` (or any other command), life gets interesting.  Using dot `.` instead of `:` colon seems to be OK.

Comment: You mention Windows — which shell will you be using on Windows?  If you're not using a Unix shell imported to Windows, you're in for a tough time making the same code work on both platforms.  If you're using a Unix shell on Windows too, then there shouldn't be any major issues.  Did the suggestion of using an associative array help at all?

Comment: declare -A npm_config; npm_config["myscope:npmKey"]=npmValue; echo ${npm_config["myscope:npmKey"]} worked but to do it as envriroment parameter I need to add the EXPORT before the npm_config and then I got the same error

Comment: Maybe you can't export arrays.  I seem to remember a (serious security) bug due to export of functions or arrays (probably functions) — ShellShock was its name.  And my Bash 4.3 doesn't seem to export (associative) arrays, though it gives no error; ditto functions.  So, this may be a non-starter if you must have the information in the environment.  You'll have to go back to creating anodyne variable names without the special characters in them.  Ah well, it was worth a try.

Comment: Could we have a short chat ?

Comment: Not now. I’m in bed.

Comment: First thanks for all the help m I trued your approach with the associative then it worked but then I didn't see that the npm config list was updated. did I miss something ? do I have a way to check it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the commonly used unix shells will let you create a var whose name includes characters not legal in an identifier (typically letters, digits and underscore). The simplest workaround is to use the `env` command since it doesn't impose any restrictions on the strings it puts in the environment. For example, `env a:b=c a_cmd` where `a_cmd` is whatever command needs that environment string. If you want it to be part of the shell's environment do `exec env a:b=c $SHELL`. Obviously the new shell won't be able to use that var since `$a:b` is not a valid var reference even if you enclose the var name in braces.